# where will i get ActivePivot.lic for ActivePivot In Memory Analytical tool. I am trying to run MDX query from Java

Tags: java, activepivot

where will i get ActivePivot.lic for ActivePivot In Memory Analytical tool. I am trying to run MDX query from Java. But getting below error,

> SEVERE: Error loading Quartet FS license: License could not be found
>   either in the classpath (ActivePivot.lic) neither at the system
>   property location 'activepivot.license' = null neither at the
>   environment variable location 'ACTIVEPIVOT_LICENSE' = null
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'cubeJettyConfig': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: protected com.qfs.store.IDatastore
>   com.met.oxf.qfs.cfg.CubeJettyConfig.datastore; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'datastore' defined in class
>   com.met.oxf.qfs.cfg.DatastoreConfig: Instantiation of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public com.qfs.store.IDatastore
>   com.met.oxf.qfs.cfg.DatastoreConfig.datastore(com.quartetfs.biz.pivot.definitions.IActivePivotManagerDescription)]
>   threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The current license does not
>   enable the 'datastore' component, only one store can be defined in the
>   schema, instead of 10

Comment: I'm deleting the `mdx` tag as this seems to be only ver very loosely related. If the user adds some `mdx` code then I could obliviously be added back. Added the `java` tag as it looks more related to `java`.

Answer (score 2):

Can you contact the person who generated the license for you through QFS jira
It seems you do not have datastore module enabled and your intance uses 10 stores
This is why you have such message

Comment: can you also add the full stack where we see the info related to the licensing environment